# Require multiple api files nodejs

Tags: node.js

My node.js app is set up where I have an `/app/api` folder, which has several subfolders and subfiles as such:

`/app/api/admin/admin_api.js`

`/app/api/admin/another_admin_api.js`

`/app/api/general/generic_api.js`

`/app/api/general/another_generic_api.js`

`...`

Is there a way I can tell my app to use & require ALL of the .js files in `/app/api`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution would be to create an `index.js` in `/app/api` and export your modules from it.

**e.g** `/app/api/index.js` :

```
const file1 = require('./file1.js');
const file2 = require('./file2.js');

module.exports = {
  file1: file1,
  file2: file2
};
```

Now when you require the folder `/app/api` (`const api = require('./app/api')`) your modules will be available through `api`.

You also can use something like [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) or [`require-all`](https://github.com/felixge/node-require-all).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Browsing.js or https://www.npmjs.com/package/bundle-up2 based on your requirements.
Although I would recommend not bundling if you are working on API side of nodejs for sake of readability. Browsify should fit your requirement if you are working on client side scripting.